# Unable to push code to fresh Dokku container: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile

Tags: node.js, docker, dokku

On my server I installed dokku and created a new App: myNodeApp

$ dokku apps:create myNodeApp

On my local repo I added the dokku remote and want now to push the existing code to my container, after git add . :

```
$ git push dokku main
Enumerating objects: 1119, done.
Counting objects: 100% (1119/1119), done.
Delta compression using up to 20 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (760/760), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1119/1119), 92.80 MiB | 11.25 MiB/s, done.
Total 1119 (delta 577), reused 727 (delta 310), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (577/577), done.
-----> Set main to DOKKU_DEPLOY_BRANCH.
-----> Cleaning up...
-----> Building myNodeApp from herokuish
remote: time="2023-02-18T21:02:28Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: "
remote: docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/apparmor/exec: no such file or directory: unknown.
remote:  !     Failure extracting app code
remote:  !     Removing invalid image tag dokku/myNodeApp:latest
remote:  !     App build failed
To serversIP:myNodeApp
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'serversIP:myNodeApp'
(base)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [a Docker issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/44900). Docker v23 accidentally added a hard dependency on AppArmor, and v23.0.1 implemented an incorrect fix, changing the error message to the one you encountered.

For the moment, the fix is one of:

a) Downgrade Docker to below v23

b) Install the `apparmor` package (I also had to reboot)

c) [The issue for the new error](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/44970) has been closed and is marked to go out in v23.0.2.

Comment: How can I do those solutions for Dokku? Since I can't install AppArmor for Dokku.. should I just downgrade Dokku? (not docker!)

Comment: I went from V 0.30.0 to V 0.29.0 Dokku - nothing changed.

Comment: You should be able to use AppArmor with Dokku? It works for me, and I don't see any mention in the Dokku docs about it being disallowed.

Comment: Changing the Dokku version will not affect this problem - it's an issue with the Docker daemon.

Comment: by "install AppArmor" you mean an app that runs on ubuntu? because somewhen in time there was also the AppArmor Dokku plugin.. and also this way: `dokku config:set <app-name> DOKKU_APPARMOR_ENABLED=0` but that also did not work. I lost so much time and nerves :'(

Comment: I think what I did was `sudo apt install apparmor`, then reboot.

Comment: Spiffytech, you little angle.. god send you I know.. must be, because it's unbelievable it worked.. but since I don't believe in angles and god and so on I got just another error. with resolving node version. I'll make a new thread. thx