# failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to a

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to turn on a server on my pterodactyl panel but this error is occuring

```
container@pterodactyl~ Error Event [345f53a4-204c-4d55-929f-a77538e97888]: environment/docker: failed to start container: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/apparmor/exec: no such file or directory: unknown
```

container@pterodactyl~ Error Event [345f53a4-204c-4d55-929f-a77538e97888]: environment/docker: failed to start container: Error response from daemon: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile: write /proc/self/attr/apparmor/exec: no such file or directory: unknown

Comment: Are you using exactly Docker 23.0.0 or 23.0.1?  [Unable to push code to fresh Dokku container: unable to apply apparmor profile: apparmor failed to apply profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75496410/unable-to-push-code-to-fresh-dokku-container-unable-to-apply-apparmor-profile) suggests a bug in exactly that Docker engine version.